# C# namespace impact on speed

Tags: c#, performance

I was wondering if there is some difference in performance between declaring a namespace with `using` keyword, or referencing it directly each time?

Comment: What kind of performance are you talking about? Compile time or runtime? Because 'using' is only related to compile time.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this question gets "too broad" close votes?

Comment: @Heinzi Probably because users want to close that question no matter on the actual reason. I feel also like closing, but don´t know any good reason to do so. Only valid reason that comes to my mind is "unclaer what you´re asking" as Rvdk already mentioned (although without saying anything on closing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At execution time, there is no difference, since both options compile to the same IL code.

Theoretically, there *might* be a difference in compilation time, but I doubt that it is even measurable.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no difference. The compiler output will be identical.

However, importing a namespace with a `using` directive will remove clutter from your code and generally help improve readability.